# Android video view transformations and effects

Tags: android, video

I have a couple questions on playing videos in android.

Currently I am using the videoview, and can play a video, no problems at all.  However I would like to do some effects on the video.  I would like to perform the following:

-mirror video
-overlay one video on another video
-trim video

So far based on my searching it doesn't appear there is any way to do this through the java api, and that I would need to use ffmpeg and the NDK to perform these types of effects.

Has anyone been able to achieve the above without going that route?

**UPDATE**

So I have moved on to the NDK.  I have this working using FFmpeg, and am able to play a video via glsurface view, the problem I am having now is that FFmpeg is not detecting the video orientation correctly.  For example if I record in portrait mode, it is showing the video in landscape and sidways, when playing the same video in videoview, or the built in movie play it plays it with the correct orientation.  Does anyone know how to get the orientation correct?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31958741/1118886)

Comment: how did you get a video view working? I'm trying to do that on top of an opengl native app in c++, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I proceeded down the NDK route, and am working through some snags, the followup question can be found here.  Marking this as answered as it appears the only way to do what I want is to use the NDK.

[android ffmpeg opengl es render movie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867616/android-ffmpeg-opengl-es-render-movie)